# Windows 10 date and time malfunctioning after VT-x is enabled

Tags: windows-10, vt-x

I enabled VT-x from BIOS to run some android emulators. Everything seems fine, but then each time I started my computer after some down time, the clock in Windows 10 is not showing the right time. The deviation could be hours and there is no obvious pattern associated with it.

Any idea about how can I resolve this? If VT-x is disabled then everything's fine. My motherboard is ASUS Z87 Pro and CPU is Core i5-4670. My system is Windows 10 Pro up to date.

Update: It seems that the clock is just stop ticking after shutdown. The system time after boot is the time when it was shut down last time.

Update 2: Found this thread discussing similar issue but not specific to vt-x options and there is no solution there. https://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-35490.html

Comment: Sounds like your NTP source isn't reachable.

Comment: @Ramhound I can manually connect after boot though. Even if it's the case, I assume the clock on CMOS should work?

Comment: Not if the battery is dead.  If your asking if there is a connect to your clock problem and vt-x being unable that's very likely despite what it looks like.  Try a different NTP source or at least verify you can ping your current source.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't unplug the power line so the motherboard should always have power supply.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be not related to vt-x, but a deficit of the motherboard which can be triggered by changing CPU settings.

Fixed by updating to newest BIOS firmware.